# Box Shadow only in the middle(Left-right) horizontaly

Tags: html, css

[image: Box shadow should be in the middle and not in the corners(left,right sides).]

I am trying to achieve box shadow similar in the image. I have tried different solutions but shadow keeps appearing on the entire box than only in the middle.

**HTML**

```
<div id="login" class="animate form">
    <div class="login-header"><h2>Sign In to the world of <span>"I want Ride!"</span></h2></div>
    <form  action="form.php" autocomplete="on">
        <h1>Log in</h1>
        <p> 
           <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" ></label>
           <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com"/>
        </p>
        <p> 
           <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"></label>
           <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
        </p>
        <p class="forgot-pass">
           <a href="#" class="to_register">Forgot your Password?</a>
        </p>
        <p class="keeplogin"> 
           <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
           <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
        </p>
        <p class="login button"> 
           <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </p>
        <p class="change_link">
           Not a member yet ?
           <a href="#" class="to_register">Sign Up Now</a>
        </p>
    </form>
    <div class="close-btn"><img src="images/close.png" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#login {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 35px 0;
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109, 0.7), 0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109, 0.7), 0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
    box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109, 0.7), 0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple way of doing this would be to make use of pseudo-elements and put a shadow on those. Then position them `absolute`ly `relative` to the left and right of your main `div`, with a lower `z-index`. Add `border-radius` for extra radial effect.

***For example:***

```css
#login {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 32px;
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, 0.8);
}
#login::before, #login::after { 
    content: ''; position: absolute; z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border-radius: 50%;
}
#login::before { top: 15%; left: 0; width: 10%; height: 70%; }
#login::after { top: 15%; right: 0; width: 10%; height: 70%; }
```

```html
<div id="login"></div>
```

*Test Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/12k08ksj/1/*